# order of calling functions javascript

Tags: javascript, order-of-execution

I have three functions in javascript, `parsing`, `init` and `animate`. `Parsing` has to be called first because without it, the `positions` array isn't modified, which the function `init` needs. Weirdly enough, animate needs the `controls` variable created by `init` but they used to be called at the same time and it worked before. I've tried every combination possible of calling the functions, but either `controls` is undefined or `positions` is. This is the last iteration of my code.

```
var positions = [];
parsing();

function parsing() {
    fetch('Petit_film_256_atomes.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
        const arr = text.split('\n')
            .map(line => line.trim())
            .map((arr) => arr.split(' '))
            .map(([size, x, y, z]) => ({ 
                  size: Number(size), 
                  x: Number(x), 
                  y: Number(y), 
                  z: Number(z) 
            }));
            while (arr.length > 0) {
                positions.push(arr.splice(0, size).slice(2));
            }
        init();
        animate();
    })
}
...
function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    ...
    console.log(positions);
    for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        atom = sphere.clone();
        atom.position.set( positions[0][i].x, positions[0][i].y, positions[0][i].z );
        scene.add( atom );
        group.push( atom );
    }
    ...
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);    
}

function animate() {
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     renderer.render(scene, camera);
     controls.update();
}
```

Also, the `console.log(positions)` shows a non empty array yet the error displayed is still that `positions` is undefined. Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Why don't you try calling animate in init as a last statement rather than calling from parsing method?

Comment: it gives the same error as before.. that "positions" is undefined despite it being filled

Comment: do you know which line gives you `positions undefined` error?

Comment: atom.position.set( positions[0][i].x, positions[0][i].y, positions[0][i].z ); from the init function